# What is the significance of flowers in Hinduism?

Tags: gods, belief, practice, festivals

What is the significance of flowers in Hinduism?

Why are temple decorated with flowers and why are Gods pleased with flowers?

Comment: Flowers denote Akasha Tattva in the Panchopachara offerings given to deities.

Comment: It is just to purify our Mind. by offering to God something which we feel is very pure, we feel pure and we are cleansed internally. God in reality accepts any offering from a pure Heart. All these rituals are therefore aimed at attaining the purification of the Mind (or purification of the heart). This is the spiritual prespective.

Answer (score 8):

In [Bhavanopanishat](http://www.astrojyoti.com/shodasaupacharas-2.htm) we find some beautiful philosophical symbolism explaining   the actual significances of worshiping Gods with the [Shodasa Upacharas](https://premaarpan.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/shodasha-upachara-puja-worship-of-lord-ritualistically/).

The explanations are given in the context of Devi Puja but readily can be applied to other Deities as well.

For Pushpam(flowers), which is one of the Pancha as well as Shodasa Upacharas,the following explanation is given:

> 11. Pushpam – Offering flowers and doing pooja.
>
> **Sutra 38. “Ahimsa prathama pushpam, pushpamindriyanigraha dayakshmagyanapushpam panchapushpam tatahpara”**
>
> **Ahimsa** or non violence, **indriya nigraha** or control over the senses, **daya** or kindness, **kshama** or forgiveness and **gyana**
>   or knowledge are called the pancha pushpas or five flowers with which
>   we can control our ahamkara or ego and surrender to God. Hence
>   worshiping the Deity with flowers is symbolic of controlling these
>   and surrendering to God

**So someone,who practices Ahimsa,Indriya nigraha,Daya,Kshama & Knowledge.is already worshiping God with 5 flowers even if he is not actually doing ritualistic worship.**

However, what Nithin said(in comment) is also technically correct :

> Flowers denote Akasha Tattva in the Panchopachara offerings given to
>   deities. – Nithin Sridhar

Offering flowers is said to satisfy the Akasha(Ether) Tatva(element) aspect of the Deity.

The correlations of the Pancha Upacharas with the Pancha Tatvas are as follows:

> oṁ laṁ pṛthivy-ātmane gandhaṁ parikalpayāmi |
>   I offer   scent   in  the form    of  the element earth.
>
> **oṁ haṁ ākāś-ātmane puṣpaṁ parikalpayāmi |
>   I offer   flowers in  the form    of  the element ether**.
>
> oṁ yaṁ vāyur-ātmane dhūpaṁ parikalpayāmi |
>   I offer   incense in  the form    of  the element wind.
>
> oṁ raṁ tejātmane dīpaṁ parikalpayāmi |
>   I offer   light   in  the form    of  the element fire.
>
> oṁ vaṁ amṛtātmane neivedyaṁ parikalpayāmi |
>   I offer   food        in  the form    of  the element water.
>
> oṁ saṁ sarvātmane tāmbūlaṁ parikalpayāmi |
>   I offer   betel   in  the form    of  the entire  Universe.

[image]

The Kularnava Tantra gives yet another symbolic explanation of the term "PUSPA" :

> Puspa: Because it increases merit, *punya*, removes
>   the heap of sin, *papa*, yield much wealth , *puskalartha*,
>   it is called puspa.

[image]

As regards decorating temples with flowers ,i don't think there are any other significance of it besides decorating the temple & making it look good.

Just as we decorate our own rooms and houses with flower to increase the aesthetic aspect.Similarly here,Also flowers emit fragrance.

Comment: Good explanation.

Comment: @Rickross are you a Shakta?