# Flowers offered to God

Tags: belief, worship, superstitions

In our house, they say Marigold flower should not be offered to God, Is there any such belief?? What is the significance of particular flower being offered to God?

Comment: And what are the reasons for not offering marigold flowers?

Comment: Related: [What is the significance of flowers in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9149/277)

Comment: I have seen marigolds offered.

Comment: In Southern India both vaishnavite and saivite temples marigold flower is not considered for archana for God. Instead it is used for spilling on the dead body procession by non Brahmins. In northern India for deities they offer this flower.